# How to use multiple inner joins for visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am looking for a way to use 2 inner joins so I can link 3 databases together.
I currently use this :

```
 rs.Open "select * from School inner join Name on School.ID = Name.ID", db, 3, 3
```

I need to add the database called Opdracht. After the DB are linked I want to link all the IDs together. Like in the code above but then 3 IDs.

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific syntax will depend on the database / driver you are using but you simply add another JOIN statement. I prefer building a string and assigning the string as it makes the code easier to read.

```
...
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM (School " & _
           "INNER JOIN Name ON School.ID = Name.ID) " & _
           "INNER JOIN Opdracht ON Opdracht.ID = Name.ID"

rs.Open strSQL, db, 3, 3
...
```

Comment: Hello, When I try your code, I get the syntax error: _(Missing operator) in query expression 'School.ID = Name.ID INNER JOIN Opdracht ON Opdracht.ID = Name.ID'._ I use acces 2000 DB

Comment: @user2479441 It's been a little longer than forever since I've written a query for Access, but I remember the FROM portion of teh query needs brackets in a multliple join statement. I don't remember the exact syntax, but I have updated my answer with how I think it should be.